# Sending POST data from inside a Django template 'for loop'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

With this HTML:

```
...

    {% for thing in things %}
        <form method="post">
             {% csrf_token %}
             {{ thing.name }}
             {{ form.value }}
             <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    {% endfor %}
...
```

My website lists multiple 'things' from my database, so there can be many forms generated on the one page. How can I somehow determine in my views.py, which 'thing's' form is being submitted?

**More elaboration:**

Imagine you have a page of objects listed one after the other, and each object has a like button associated with it, that adds a like to the object it is next to. That's essentially what I'm trying to do here.

The problem is, I have a form that can process the like, but how do I take that like and add it to the object that it's displayed next to on the page? (by the aforementioned 'for loop')

---

I'm completely confused on how to go about this, am I looking at the problem the wrong way, or is there a standard idiom around this problem that I don't know about?

Thank you :)

Comment: didn't understand your question.Can you more elaborate on this?

Comment: There are actually individual `<form>` tags around all those forms, are there? Why do you want to handle multiple forms with a single view? Why not point the forms to different URLs/different views? Still, if you really need to handle multiple submits with a single view, why not include an `<input type='hidden' value='thisisform1' />` field?

Comment: @dhke yes sorry that was a typo! There is indeed <form> tags around those forms.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava I'm trying to figure out how I can elaborate on my question. I'm finding it really difficult to explain clearer (this is just my lack of understanding I'm sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common design pattern for model instance updates is to provide the primary key of an object in the url where you are submitting your post data.

```
# urls.py

from django.conf.urls import *
from library.views import UpdateThing

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^update_thing/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)$', UpdateThing.as_view(), name='update_thing'),

# views.py

def my_view(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        object = thing.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = MyModelForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=object)

    if form.is_valid():
        ...
```

Now, let's specify (using Django's url template tag) that we want to submit post data for each object to the correct url.

```
{% for thing in things %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'update_thing' thing.pk %}">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ thing.name }}
         {{ form.value }}
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
{% endfor %}
```

The `url` tag does a reverse lookup through your urls for the `name` kwarg supplied for a given url, and accepting positional arguments (such as, in this case, thing.pk) and, when needed, keyword arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic answer! So this is probably a stupid question, but what is the return call at the end of that view?

Comment: Whatever you want it to be :) If I were building this, I'd submit the 'like' clicks via AJAX and update the displayed element to show the object as liked/unliked upon a successful response. For that, I generally use a [JsonResponse] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) as the return value of a view and update elements via JQuery on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to handle multiple forms of the same kind on one page with Django is to use [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/).

It handles the annoying details like displaying errors on one form while preserving the input on others etc.

However, in your specific case that might be overkill. If you just want to create a like for an object, there isn't really any user input that needs to be validated, so you don't really need a form. Just perform a POST to a specified URL, maybe with Javascript. If the user messes with the URL, you display a 404.